# Strategy to git revert a set of commits on a feature branch, then prepare for another PR to revert the revert

Tags: git

Just so it's clear, I've seen "git revert", and I don't believe it helps me.  I'll explain what I want and why "git revert" doesn't help.

I created a PR (one in each of two repositories, in fact) for some experimental changes that need to be merged to master and deployed to our test server. It's not practical to deploy the PR to the test server.  Those PRs have now been merged.  We will be doing some testing of those changes over the next few days.

However, these experimental changes should not go into a release.  After I merged the PRs, I discovered that the next release branch is being cut from master this evening or tomorrow morning.  I will have time to revert the changes in the release branch after it is cut, but I definitely will have to do that, if I don't revert the changes before the branch is cut.

We use trunk-based development, and all changes go into PRs which are then merged to master and then the commits of those PRs are cherry picked to the release branch (for changes destined for the release branch that are made after the release branch is cut).  We create a feature branch off of the release branch, cherry pick into that, and then merge that to the release branch.

Whether I revert the changes before or after the release branch is cut, I will have to construct a feature branch with the specific changes reverted.  Fortunately the number of changes are small, so I could do this manually if I had to.  I would have liked to use "git revert", but from what I understand, I would have to use "git revert" when I have the master branch checked out.  That would put the commits in the master branch of my local repository, which I can't push the remote, as it's not in a feature branch.

I would really like "git revert" to create the commits reverting the specific commits on the master branch, but put them into a feature branch that I designate.  I don't believe it can do that.

Is there some way I can use "git revert" on the local master branch, but then move those commits to a feature branch?

Once I get these changes reverted, I will then have to create another PR that reverts the reverted commits, getting back to the experimental changes I need to test.

How can I manage this process properly using git, instead of making these changes manually?

Comment: "I don't believe it can do that" Why can't you? Why not just make a branch and say `git revert <badcommit>`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow accurately as you are using many branches to explain the problem. If I understood you right, you created a feature branch, it's already merged to master. You would like to create a different PR to revert those changes? You can start a branch from master and ask to revert all the revisions that made up the original PR without any problem....then merge to master your new PR and the original PR is gone.... well, the content, because the original revisions will stay in master.

If that is what you want, I would do it a little less cumbersome without the reverts.

```
git checkout revision-from-master-where-first-pr-started
git reset --soft first-pr-branch
# at this point all changes required to revert the first PR are in index
git commit -m 'reverting feature X'
# created a single revision to revert everything
git rebase --onto master HEAD~ HEAD # moved that revision to the tip of master
git checkout -b feature-reversal
# the reversal is in the branch you just created, a single revision
```